# Solr Edismax query wrongly produces result

Tags: solr, edismax, query-parser

I have 2 types of solr query.One uses EDisMax parser and other one uses standard query parser as default.Following are the 2 query I have used.Purpose of the query is document that doesn't contains  following word ELM,PST,June.

**EDisMax Query**

*q= content:(-EML -PST -June) OR contentenstem:(-EML -PST -June)&start=0&rows=25
&defType=edismax&fl=content filename*

It produces about 12232 results; In which 4292 results of docs contains any of the given query string that EML or PST or June.So 4292 result docs are wrong.

***Standard parser Query***

query:q=size:[ 0 TO * ]&fq=content:( -EML  -PST -June  )&fq=contentenstem:( -EML  -PST -June  )&start=0&rows=25&fl=content file name

It produces about 7940 result.

Why EDisMax query failed for this query;How to achieve the right result with use of EDisMax parser query

If we know how EDisMax and Standard query parser parses AND & OR Boolean query on the document, we may get the answer for why different doc count occurred for different parser.

Comment: Could you try switching `OR` to `AND` in the EDisMax query. Syou seem to have AND-ed it in the Standard parser Query.

Comment: Thanks Mowgli....When am using AND in the query it gives result same as the result given by standard query parser.But why it so....? why not in query with OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch `OR` to `AND` in the EDisMax query. `OR` and `AND` act differently:

`OR` will cause results that meet one or both of your restrictions (for content and contentstem).

`AND` is stricter: results must meet both the restrictions.